# I need to assign string to array columns after split method c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods, split

I have a multidimensional array that takes lines based on user input like(n lines/4col )
and I have a string of 4 numbers in a line separated by 1 space: 10.00 20.00 30.00 40.00. I need to assign each number to a column in 1 line. The code that I have until now:

```
         int storeNumbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        string[,] storesemesterProfit = new string[storeNumbers, 4];

        for(int m=0; m<storeNumbers; m++)
        {
            for(int n=0; n < 4; n++)
            {
               
               string inputData = Console.ReadLine()
               string [] numb = inputData.Split(' ');
               storesemesterProfit[m, n] = numb ; // i need help here
```

Comment: Posting some input data (and/or exp. output) helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
int storeNumbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var storesemesterProfit = new decimal[storeNumbers, 4];

for (var m = 0; m < storeNumbers; m++)
{
   string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
   var numb = inputData.Split(' ');
   for (int n = 0; n < Math.Min(4, numb.Length); n++)
      storesemesterProfit[m, n] = decimal.Parse(numb[n]);
}
```

<sub>***Fair warning.** This will likely explode if the user enters some bad data. I suggest taking a look at `TryParse` Methods*</sub>